# How to convert a date from date object to string object

Tags: java, junit

This test fails. I am passing in the current date and using a method that I wrote to convert the date into an object. When I return it since it is an object. When I write my assertion it fails. I call the tostring method on date as when the object is returned it is like a string since a string is an object.

```
@Test
   public void testOrder5() throws Exception {
      Phone input = new DefaultPhone();
      Date date = new Date();
      input.setCreatedDate(date); // passing in date object
      PhoneObj output = Book.change(input); //pases input to change method to convert date to phone object
      assertThat(output.getCreatedDate(), is(date.toString()));
   }
```

Here is my failing error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "Wed Oct 09 12:03:17 EDT 2013"
     got: "2013-10-09T12:03:17-04:00"

at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:780)
at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:738)
at ca.on.oicr.DtosTest.testOrder5(DtosTest.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

In my conversion change method I have

```
public static PhoneObj change(Order from) {
     PhoneObj phoneobj = new OrderDto();
    if (from.getCreatedDate() != null) {
             phoneobj.setCreatedDate(dateTimeFormatter.print(from.getCreatedDate().getTime()));
          }
return phoneobj;
}
```

I tried the folllowing from the suggestions but it did not work

```
   @Test
   public void testOrder5() throws Exception {
      Phone input = new Defaultphone();
      SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
      Date date = new Date();
      String str = date.toString();
      input.setCreatedDate(date);
      Date date1 = sf.parse(str);
      PhoneObj output = Book.change(input);
      assertThat(output.getCreatedDate(), is((date1.toString())));
   }
```

Says date is not parseable

Comment: Use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert between `Date`s and `String`s, and vice versa.

Comment: Note: In order to avoid messes like this, one simple solution is to just pass around a double or a long with the unix timestamp in it and only convert it to textual format when you need to show it to the user.  Plays well with databases, conversion to/from other languages (including JS) is direct, handles time zones correctly.  Is just plain simple.

Comment: Whenever you need to identify or compare objects based on an attribute, you should ensure that that attribute is simple and reproducible.  Attributes that have local or regional formatting dependencies can be a mess to use as an identity UNLESS you standardize the format internally.  In this case, the simplest, most error-proof comparison you can make is by simply comparing the long integers that are wrapped within Date objects.  Long integers are simple and there are no formatting complexities with them.  I would not use doubles, because they are always approximate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to compare both `Date` in the same format. In the Test below I am comparing the Strings that got generated by the formatter.

```
@Test
   public void testOrder5() throws Exception {
      SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
      Phone input = new DefaultPhone();
      Date date = new Date();
      input.setCreatedDate(date); // passing in date object
      PhoneObj output = Book.change(input); //pases input to change method to convert date to phone object
      assertThat(sf.format((Date)(output.getCreatedDate())), sf.format(date));
   }
```

Comment: I get this error now

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
 at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:301)
 at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
 at ca.on.oicr.DtosTest.testOrder5(DtosTest.java:64)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall

Comment: PhoneObj#getCreatedDate() isn't returning a Date?

Comment: Now cannot cast from String to Date

Comment: Can you change the type of `PhoneObj#createdDate`in `Date` or change the return type of `PhoneObj#getCreatedDate()` to `Date`?

Comment: I did assertThat(output.getCreatedDate(), is(sf.format(date).toString()));

this got me close now its asserting but I am missing the ending

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "2013-07-09T14:07:45"
     got: "2013-10-09T14:07:45-04:00"

Comment: what variable would I add onto yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss to get the -4:00

Answer (score 1):

There is code you are not showing, but I would suggest you either compare `Date` object or compare `String` object that were generated with a `SimpleDateFormat` using the same format.

Your problem is that you compare two `String`s obtained from the same `Date` but with different formats.

Comment: how would I get the assertion date string in the same format?

Comment: I did the following but it did not work

   @Test
   public void testOrder5() throws Exception {
      Order input = new DefaultOrder();
      SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
      Date date = new Date();
      String str = date.toString();
      input.setCreatedDate(date);
      Date date1 = sf.parse(str);
      OrderDto output = Dtos.asDto(input);
      assertThat(output.getCreatedDate(), is((date1.toString())));
   }